# Validity of a proof requiring a non-terminating process?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-theory

I was trying to prove directly that in a Hausdorff space, if $p \in A$ is a limit point of $A$, then every neighborhood of $p$ contains infinitely many points of $A$. The proof I remember seeing a while back drew a contradiction, but I wanted to try doing it more directly.

I figured you could start with a neighborhood $U$ of $p$, and then use the limit point condition to get that it contains a point $a_1$ of $A$, then use the Hausdorff condition to get two disjoint neighborhoods $N_1,N_1'$ of $p$ and $a_1$, and then consider $N_1 \cap U$ which is also a neighborhood of $p$ disjoint from $N_1'$ (and still contained in $U$) and use the limit point condition again to get a new point $a_2$ inside $N_1 \cap U$ and then use the Hausdorff condition again, so on and so forth.

It seems reasonable enough, but it started sounding suspiciously like trying to use induction on an infinite set. Is that what this construction really is? I suppose that even though I feel that I am constructing something infinite, that at each stage I really only have finitely many objects, so I can never actually get to the part where I will have the infinite set that I am looking to make. So in general is it not valid to give the recipe for some non-terminating process and claim that it leads to a valid construction?

Comment: A full formalization would require an application of the axiom of choice and then construct the sequence of points $a_i$ and sets $N_i, N_i'$ by recursion.  (Or use the axiom of countable dependent choice.)  But informally, the argument is valid.

Comment: What definition of ​ "limit point" ​ are you using? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: The one that says $p$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if every neighborhood of $p$ contains a point $a \in A$ such that $p \neq a$.

Comment: Your doubt is similar to the doubt that there are infinitely many natural numbers. Every time you have to deal with natural numbers you only work with finitely many of them, I mean at every step you have only $1, \dots  ,n$, so how can they be infinitely many?

Comment: As mentioned by Daniel, this uses [Dependent Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice) on pairs ​ $\langle$a , A$\rangle$ . ​ ​ ​ Your reasoning leads to the conclusion that every neighborhood has a _countably_ infinite set of points in A, from which it would follow that there are no [Dedekind cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set#History), since they can have a [particular point topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology). ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ (... continued) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: (continued ...) ​ Proving the non-existence of Dedekind cardinals requires some [Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) $\hspace{1.24 in}$ - Non-obviously, [CC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice) is enough. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Hausdorff is overkill. $T_1$ is quite enough.

Comment: @RickyDemer. Without AC, an argument by contradiction works, assuming that infinite means  not Tarski-finite. But a direct proof is asked for.  I wonder if a direct proof could be cooked up in ZF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be seen as a completely valid recursive construction of an infinite subset. Let's formalise it:

Let $p$ be a limit point of the infinite set $A$ in a $T_1$ space $X$.
Let $O$ be an open neighbourhood of $p$. First pick $a_0 \in O \cap A$ with $p \neq a$, which is possible as $p \in A'$.

We will define $a_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, at stage $n$:

- all $a_i, i \le n$ are pairwise distinct and all distinct from $p$.
- all $a_i \in A \cap O ,i \le n$.

Now we find $a_{n+1}$ as follows: note that $F = \{a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ is finite, so $X \setminus F$ is open in $X$ by $T_1$-ness, and is a neighborhood of $p$.
Then $O \cap (X\setminus F)$ is also a neighbourhood of $p$ so intersects $A \setminus \{p\}$, pick $a_{n+1} \in A \cap (X\setminus F) \cap (O \setminus \{p\})$. Then the first condition is met for $a_{n+1}$, as $a_{n+1} \notin F$ and by construction it's not $p$, and the second condition is also clear.

As stage $0$ was also trivially satisfied, standard recursion theorems (e.g. see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42814/need-help-with-recursion-theorem-set-theory)) then tell us that $B = \{a_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a well-defined set, and the first condition tells us that $B$ is infinite and the second that $B \subseteq A \cap O$, as required.

Answer (score 1):

Arguments that seem to involve an infinite process can often be rephrased as involving a notion of induction. In this case, I would prove the following statement by induction:

> For every natural number $n$, every neighbourhood of a limit point $p$
>   contains at least $n$ points from $A$.

The argument outlined in the question can be easily modified to show this.

(This will of course only establish that there are countably many such points from $A$ in every neighbourhood.)

Answer (score 0):

You have constructed an infinite sequence of distinct points,
inside U.  Thus U is infinite.

Exercise.  Show the proposition holds for all T1 spaces.

Comment: In a first countable space you'd set up the proof differently. The way the OP suggested it, does not garantuee convergence in a first countable space.